# How do I connect Asus Zendisk AS400?

Tags: asus, external-hdd, usb-drive

How can I mount ZENDISK AS400? Ubuntu doesn't mount hdd, only u3 cd image as `/dev/sr0`.

This affects all versions including Ubuntu 16.04.1, 12.04, etc.

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0b05:17b4 ASUSTek Computer, Inc.
```

`lsscsi`:

```
[0:0:0:0] disk ATA ADATA XM11 128GB BBF0 /dev/sda
[6:0:0:0] disk USB3.0 D Super Speed Mass 0 -
[6:0:0:1] cd/dvd ASMT VirtualCDROM /dev/sr0
```

`fdisk -l`:

```
not show this disk
```

`sg_map -i`:

```
/dev/sg0 /dev/sda ATA ADATA XM11 128GB BBF0
/dev/sg1 USB3.0 D Super Speed Mass 0
/dev/sg2 /dev/sr0 ASMT VirtualCDROM
```

`u3-tool -i /dev/sg1`:

```
u3_partition_info() failed: Device reported command failed: status 1
```

`mount /dev/sg1 /mnt`:

```
mount: /dev/sg1 is not a block device
```

`dmesg`:

```
 [ 1682.332885] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 5
 [ 1688.382795] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
 [ 1688.589306] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0b05, idProduct=17b4
 [ 1688.589317] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
 [ 1688.589323] usb 2-1.2: Product: Super Speed Mass Storage
 [ 1688.589328] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: USB3.0 Device
 [ 1688.589333] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 2020120509000060
 [ 1688.589970] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
 [ 1688.593042] scsi host8: usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
 [ 1689.628327] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access USB3.0 D Super Speed Mass 0 PQ: 1 ANSI: 0
 [ 1689.629210] scsi 8:0:0:1: CD-ROM ASMT VirtualCDROM PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
 [ 1689.630743] scsi 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
 [ 1689.632598] sr 8:0:0:1: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
 [ 1689.633127] sr 8:0:0:1: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
 [ 1689.633706] sr 8:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
```

`usb-devices`:

```
T: Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#= 1 Spd=480 MxCh= 2
D: Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs= 1
P: Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=04.04
S: Manufacturer=Linux 4.4.0-38-generic ehci_hcd
S: Product=EHCI Host Controller
S: SerialNumber=0000:00:1a.0
C: #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA

I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
T: Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#= 2 Spd=480 MxCh= 6
D: Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs= 1
P: Vendor=8087 ProdID=0024 Rev=00.00
C: #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
    
T: Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#= 4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D: Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs= 1
P: Vendor=13d3 ProdID=5719 Rev=09.19
S: Manufacturer=Azurewave
S: Product=USB2.0 VGA Webcam
S: SerialNumber=NULL
C: #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I: If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
    
T: Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#= 1 Spd=480 MxCh= 2
D: Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs= 1
P: Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=04.04
S: Manufacturer=Linux 4.4.0-38-generic ehci_hcd
S: Product=EHCI Host Controller
S: SerialNumber=0000:00:1d.0
C: #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
  
T: Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#= 2 Spd=480 MxCh= 8
D: Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs= 1
P: Vendor=8087 ProdID=0024 Rev=00.00
C: #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
   
T: Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#= 6 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D: Ver= 2.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs= 1
P: Vendor=0b05 ProdID=17b4 Rev=01.00
S: Manufacturer=USB3.0 Device

S: Product=Super Speed Mass Storage
S: SerialNumber=2020120509000060
C: #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=0mA
I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage

T: Bus=03 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#= 1 Spd=480 MxCh= 2
D: Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs= 1
P: Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=04.04
S: Manufacturer=Linux 4.4.0-38-generic xhci-hcd
S: Product=xHCI Host Controller
S: SerialNumber=0000:03:00.0
C: #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T: Bus=04 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#= 1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 2
D: Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs= 1
P: Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=04.04
S: Manufacturer=Linux 4.4.0-38-generic xhci-hcd
S: Product=xHCI Host Controller
S: SerialNumber=0000:03:00.0
C: #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I: If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
```

`udevadm monitor`:

```
  monitor will print the received events for:
  UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
  KERNEL - the kernel uevent

 KERNEL[3234.490418] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:0/bsg/10:0:0:0
  (bsg)
  KERNEL[3234.491115] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg1
  (scsi_generic)
  KERNEL[3234.491172] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:0/scsi_device/10:0:0:0
  (scsi_device)
  KERNEL[3234.491342] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:0
  (scsi)
  KERNEL[3234.491726] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:1/bsg/10:0:0:1
  (bsg)
  UDEV [3234.493073] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:0/bsg/10:0:0:0
  (bsg)
  UDEV [3234.493366] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg1
  (scsi_generic)
  KERNEL[3234.494854] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:1/scsi_generic/sg2
  (scsi_generic)
  KERNEL[3234.494919] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:1/scsi_device/10:0:0:1
  (scsi_device)
  UDEV [3234.495152] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:1/bsg/10:0:0:1
  (bsg)
  KERNEL[3234.495754] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:1/block/sr0
  (block)
  KERNEL[3234.495830] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:1
  (scsi)
  UDEV [3234.497575] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:1/scsi_device/10:0:0:1
  (scsi_device)
  UDEV [3234.497648] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:0/scsi_device/10:0:0:0
  (scsi_device)
  UDEV [3234.497740] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:1/scsi_generic/sg2
  (scsi_generic)
  UDEV [3234.497948] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:1/block/sr0
  (block)
  UDEV [3234.499216] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:0
  (scsi)
  UDEV [3234.501017] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:1
  (scsi)
  KERNEL[3234.513688] remove /devices/virtual/bdi/11:0 (bdi)
  KERNEL[3234.513750] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0
  (scsi)
  KERNEL[3234.513784] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/scsi_host/host10
  (scsi_host)
  KERNEL[3234.513823] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10
  (scsi)
  KERNEL[3234.514090] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0 (usb)
  KERNEL[3234.514311] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2 (usb)
  UDEV [3234.516530] remove /devices/virtual/bdi/11:0 (bdi)
  UDEV [3234.516587] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/target10:0:0
  (scsi)
  UDEV [3234.516627] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10/scsi_host/host10
  (scsi_host)
  UDEV [3234.517618] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host10
  (scsi)
  UDEV [3234.519023] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0 (usb)
  UDEV [3234.522125] remove
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2 (usb)
  KERNEL[3236.767040] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2 (usb)
  KERNEL[3236.767962] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0 (usb)
  KERNEL[3236.771361] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11
  (scsi)
  KERNEL[3236.771482] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/scsi_host/host11
  (scsi_host)
  UDEV [3237.298151] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2 (usb)
  UDEV [3237.304466] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0 (usb)
  UDEV [3237.304531] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11
  (scsi)
  UDEV [3237.304574] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/scsi_host/host11
  (scsi_host)
  KERNEL[3237.770892] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0
  (scsi)
  KERNEL[3237.771016] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:0
  (scsi)
  KERNEL[3237.771196] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:0/scsi_device/11:0:0:0
  (scsi_device)
  KERNEL[3237.771346] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg1
  (scsi_generic)
  KERNEL[3237.771555] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:0/bsg/11:0:0:0
  (bsg)
  KERNEL[3237.771747] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:1
  (scsi)
  KERNEL[3237.774233] add /devices/virtual/bdi/11:0 (bdi)
  KERNEL[3237.774525] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:1/block/sr0
  (block)
  UDEV [3237.774604] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0
  (scsi)
  KERNEL[3237.774777] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:1/scsi_device/11:0:0:1
  (scsi_device)
  KERNEL[3237.775420] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:1/scsi_generic/sg2
  (scsi_generic)
  KERNEL[3237.775776] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:1/bsg/11:0:0:1
  (bsg)
  UDEV [3237.777671] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:0
  (scsi)
  KERNEL[3237.777890] change
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:1/block/sr0
  (block)
  UDEV [3237.779681] add /devices/virtual/bdi/11:0 (bdi)
  UDEV [3237.780438] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:0/scsi_device/11:0:0:0
  (scsi_device)
  UDEV [3237.780525] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:1
  (scsi)
  UDEV [3237.784366] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg1
  (scsi_generic)
  UDEV [3237.785544] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:0/bsg/11:0:0:0
  (bsg)
  UDEV [3237.786795] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:1/scsi_generic/sg2
  (scsi_generic)
  UDEV [3237.786857] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:1/scsi_device/11:0:0:1
  (scsi_device)
  UDEV [3237.787436] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:1/bsg/11:0:0:1
  (bsg)
  UDEV [3239.096620] add
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:1/block/sr0
  (block)
  UDEV [3239.137395] change
  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:1/block/sr0
  (block)
```

ubuntu bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1623419

similar problem on similar disk (debian): https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=731016

Answer (score 1):

After updating the firmware, the disk works well on Linux.

http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/Accessory/External_HDD/FW_update.zip